# Changing contents of UITextField when UIPickerView didSelectRow is called

Tags: ios, plist, uipickerview, segue

I have the following code in my `rootViewController`. In the `prepareForSegue` method, I find out which `NSObject` was selected in the `UIPickerView` on that page and populate the `UITextField` in the `DataViewController`.

```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
     {
         DataViewController *detailView = segue.destinationViewController;
         if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"dataViewSegue"])
         {
             for(NSString *parent in dictionaryKeys) {
                 NSDictionary *parentData = [dictionaryFromPlist objectForKey:parent];
                 if ([parentData objectForKey:@"Name"]== currentSite) {
                     NSLog(@"found it");

                     detailView.nameText = [parentData valueForKey:@"Name"];
                     detailView.descriptionText = [parentData valueForKey:@"Description"];
                     detailView.positionText =[parentData valueForKey:@"Position"];
                     detailView.latitudeText = [parentData valueForKey:@"Latitude"];
                     detailView.longitudeText = [parentData valueForKey:@"Longitude"];
                     detailView.gridRefText = [parentData valueForKey:@"GridRef"];
                     detailView.radioText = [parentData valueForKey:@"Radio"];
                     detailView.elevationText = [parentData valueForKey:@"Elevation"];
                     detailView.lengthText = [parentData valueForKey:@"Length"];
                     detailView.widthText = [parentData valueForKey:@"Width"];
                     detailView.phoneText = [parentData valueForKey:@"Phone"];
                     detailView.bestApproachText = [parentData valueForKey:@"BestApproach"];
                     detailView.gpsText =[parentData valueForKey:@"GPS"];
                     detailView.gridRefText = [parentData valueForKey:@"GPS"];
                     detailView.windstockState = [parentData valueForKey:@"Windsock"];
                     detailView.forbiddenSectorsText = [parentData valueForKey:@"ForbiddenSectors"];
                     detailView.hazardsText = [parentData valueForKey:@"Hazards"];
                     detailView.aircraftsustainabilityText = [parentData valueForKey:@"Sustainability"];
                     detailView.notesText = [parentData valueForKey:@"Notes"];
                     detailView.clearareaState = [parentData valueForKey:@"ClearArea"];
                     detailView.helipadState = [parentData valueForKey:@"Helipad"];
                     detailView.tdpText = [parentData valueForKey:@"TDP"];
                     detailView.ldpText = [parentData valueForKey:@"LDP"];
                     detailView.surveyingoperatorText = [parentData valueForKey:@"SurveyingOperator"];
                     detailView.surveyorText = [parentData valueForKey:@"Surveyor"];
                     detailView.authorisedbyText = [parentData valueForKey:@"AuthorisedBy"];
                     detailView.surveyordateText = [parentData valueForKey:@"SurveyorDate"];
                     detailView.authorisationdateText = [parentData valueForKey:@"AuthorisationDate"];

                     detailView.dataArray = self.landingSites;

                 }

             }
         }

     }
```

However, on the `DetailViewController`, I have another `UIPicker` where the user can again select an `NSObject`.

My question is how do I populate the `UITextField` again depending on what `NSObject` is selected in this `DataViewController`? Please note the data comes from a `Plist`. Please Help. Thanks

Comment: use Delegate method `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to set content of textfield...

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
 {
    return 1;
 }
 - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:    (NSInteger)component
 {
    return [arrOfCategory count];
 }

 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   NSString *titleRow;

   titleRow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrOfCategory objectAtIndex:row]];
   yourTextField.text = titleRow;
   return titleRow;
 }

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
  {
     selectedRow = row;
  }
```

Enjoy Coding